# UIPickerView how do I show nothing selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

With a UISegmentedControl you can bring it up initially with nothing selected.
How do I do that with a UIPickerView? It seems like the display defaults to index 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picker wheel has to rest on *some* value, so you could try adding an extra value at the top that says something like **Choose**, just like traditional drop-down menus on the desktop. Then tell your picker view delegate to ignore the item at index 0 (which would be that option).